# DATE COMPARISON in GOOGLE APP ENGINE DATASTORE / PYTHON

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I am trying to fetch records after a certain date.

I used the below in code:

```
qstr = "SELECT * FROM Comment where date > '"+str(max_date)+"' order by date desc limit 10"
comments = db.GqlQuery(qstr)
```

I have the console log I have qStr as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Comment where date > '2013-03-07 04:33:31' order by date desc limit 10"
```

But this does not yield any records (There are records in the DB).

I also tried passing as date time:

```
comments = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Comment where date > :1 order by date desc limit 10",
                                miscUtils._datetime_from_str(max_date))
```

This also does not yield any results. Can you please let me know as what I'm doing wrong?
(I'm using the following code to convert date string to date http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577135-parse-a-datetime-string-to-a-datetime-instance/)

Also, I tried debugging the statement in App Engine console, and I was not able to do so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the property type of `date` property in `Comment` kind?
i mean, is it `StringProperty` or `DateTimeProperty` ?

Comment: [look here][1]

Some date queries using ndb and datetime

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15184526/784435

Comment: I got it to work as follows:comments = db.GqlQuery("select * from Comment where date > :1 order by date desc limit "+MAX_COMMENTS_PER_FETCH_STR,
                                    datetime.datetime.strptime(max_date,  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date())

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work as follows:`comments = db.GqlQuery("select * from Comment where date > :1 order by date desc limit "+MAX_COMMENTS_PER_FETCH_STR, datetime.datetime.strptime(max_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date())`

Thanks everyone for your help