# AppEngine export Datastore Entities for certain time frame

Tags: google-app-engine

I have Entities in AppEngine that have CreateDate field.
I wish to to filter entities and export entities created in 2014.
What is the best way to do?

Comment: What have your tried ?  Have you read the docs on how to perform queries ?

Comment: Are you using ndb?  db?  django? etc??

Comment: Many duplicate questions, like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956164/ndb-query-error-with-datetime-field-google-app-engine