# Determine if an entity is created 'today'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am creating an app which, on any given day, only one entity can be created per day. Here is the model:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Since only one entity is allowed to be created per day, we will need to compare the MyModel.created property to today's date:

```
import datetime

class CreateEntity(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        my_model = MyModel.query(MyModel.created == today).get()

        if my_model:
          # print("Today's entity already exists")
        else:
          # create today's new entity
```

The problem is that I cannot compare the two dates like this. How can I check if an entity was already created 'today'?

Comment: Why can't you compare the two dates like this? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @TammoHeeren, a newly created datatime object contains a different `seconds` value, every second, so comparison would almost always return false. To get around this, I ended up using the `DateProperty` instead of the `DateTimeProperty` (see my own answer below).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing the property from `DateTimeProperty` to `DateProperty`. Now I am able to do this:

```
today_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
today_entity = MyModel.query(MyModel.created == today_date).get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `DateTime` object with a `Date` object.

Instead of

```
my_model = MyModel.query(MyModel.created == today).get()
```

use

```
my_model = MyModel.query(MyModel.created.date() == today).get()
```

Comment: I am getting the error: `'DateTimeProperty' object has no attribute 'date'`

Comment: Hmm. What attributes does it have. Is it just a string?

Comment: @THeeren it's a model property, it's not a datetime object

Comment: @THeeren, you have identified the problem for me. I have been comparing DateTime with Date objects. Thank you. I resolved it by changing the DateTimeProperty to a DateProperty. I have submitted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only one solution is to use a "range" query, here's a relevant answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14963648/762270

Answer (score 0):

You can't query by `created` property using `==` since you don't actually know the **exact** creation datetime (which is what you'll find in `created` due to the `auto_now_add=True` option)

But you could query for the most recently created entity and check if its `creation` datetime is today. Something along these lines:

```
class CreateEntity(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        # get most recently created one:
        entity_list = MyModel.query().order(-MyModel.created).fetch(limit=1)
        entity = entity_list[0] if entity_list else None
        if entity and entity.created.year  == now.year and \
                      entity.created.month == now.month and \
                      entity.created.day   == now.day:
            # print("Today's entity already exists")
        else:
            # create today's new entity
```

Or you could compute a datetime for today's 0:00:00 am and query for `created` bigger than that.

Or you could drop the `auto_now_add=True` option and explicitly set `created` to a specific time of the day (say midnight exactly) and then you can query for the datetime matching that time of day today.

Answer (score 0):

Using a range query for a single specific known value you want to lookup is overkill and expensive, I would use one of these 2 solutions:

**1 - Extra Property**

Sacrifice a little space with an extra property, though since it's one per day, it shouldn't be a big deal.

```python
from datetime import datetime


class MyModel(ndb.Model):

    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        self.date = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")

    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    date = ndb.StringProperty()


class CreateEntity(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")

        my_model = MyModel.query(MyModel.date == today).get()

        if my_model:
            logging.info("Today's entity already exists")
        else:
            # MyModel.date gets set automaticaly by _pre_put_hook
            my_model = MyModel()
            my_model.put()
            logging.info("create today's new entity")
```

**2 - Use [today] as Entity ID (preferred)**

I would rather use `today` as the **ID** for my Entity, that's the fastest/cheaper/optimal way to retrieve your entity later. It could also be a combination with something else, i.e. `ID=<userid+today>`, in case that entity is per user, or maybe just add userid as a parent (ancestor). So it would be something like this:

```python
from datetime import datetime


class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class CreateEntity(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")

        my_model = MyModel.get_by_id(today)

        if my_model:
            logging.info("Today's entity already exists")
        else:
            my_model = MyModel(id=today)
            my_model.put()
            logging.info("create today's new entity")
```